# When I try to delete an object from a list it never tells me it was found

Tags: python, list, python-3.8

When I try to delete an object from the list it never finds it and tell me that the name isn't in the list. I tried getting the title of `self._entitiesList[i]` and the one of entity but I haven't found a way to do that. I work in python 3.8. The class that has 4 attributes: title, artist, genre and duration.

Repository:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._entitiesList = []

def find_position(self, entity):
    """
    Function that returns the position of an entity
    :param entity: (object) given entity
    :return: (int) position of entity, -1 if not found
    """
    for i in range(len(self._entitiesList)):
        if self._entitiesList[i] == entity:
            return i
    return -1

def delete(self, entity):
    """
    Function that deletes a given entity
    :raise Exception: if entity does not exists
    :param entity: (object) given entity
    """
    position = self.find_position(entity)
    if position == -1:
        raise Exception("Does not exist!")
    del self._entitiesList[position]
```

Service:

```
def delete_song(self, title, artist, genre, ):
    """
    Function that deletes a song by title
    :param title: (str) song title
    """
    self._music_repository.delete(Music(title, artist, genre, float(0)))
```

for the console:

```
def __delete_song(self):
    title = input("Title: ")
    self.__music_service.delete_song(title)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new `Music` object which you're passing to `self._music_repository.delete`, which of course doesn't exist in your list since it has just been created.

When comparing custom objects, (as you do with `if self._entities_list[i] == entity`), there are two things that can happen (in the following order):

1. It calls `if self._entities_list[i].__eq__(entity)`.
2. It calls `if self._entities_list[i] is entity`.

Since you haven't defined the comparison method `def __eq__(self, other)`, python will do the second option and check for identity. Identity is **not** the same as equality.

Define the comparison method on `Music` and you should be able to compare equality.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.title == other.title and self.artist == other.artist:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I choose to say that music with the same title and the same artist are equal, but you'll have to define the logic to whatever you feel fits.

---

In my answer I've replaced your `self._entitiesList` with `self._entities_list`. **Always** stay consistent with your naming and try to follow [PEP8 naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) unless you have a good reason not to.

---

To expand on the difference between identity and equality, consider the following:

```
a = ['hello']
b = ['hello']
c = a
```

Here, `a` and `b` are equal but have different identity while `a` and `c` are equal with the same identity. In other words:

```
a is b  # False
a is c  # True
```